# Using {{ content }} and generators in Jekyll index pages

Tags: ruby, jekyll, liquid

In Jekyll, a post is displayed in its layout thusly:

```
{{ content }}
```

Any generators that might have run on that content is displayed like so:

```
{{ content | toc_generate }}
```

Unfortunately, this does not work on index pages, as `{{ content }}` displays nothing on index pages. Instead, we are told to use a for loop:

```
{% for post in site.posts %}
    {{ post.content }}
{% endfor %}
```

So, the question:

How can I get a generator to run on an index page, since I can't use `{{ content }}`?

My best guess...

```
{% for post in site.posts %}
    {{ post | toc_generator }}
{% endfor %}
```

...does nothing.

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
{% capture content %}
    {% for post in site.posts %}
        <h2>{{ post.tile }}</h2>
        {{ post.content }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endcapture %}
{{ content | toc_generator }}
{{ content }}
```

Comment: That did it and it seems so simple, now that I think about it. David, my internet friend, you have been a huge help with my Jekyll questions recently.